# Get value from edittext in custom dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, customdialog

I have an custom dialog and 2 edittext

```
final Dialog add_block_dialog = new Dialog(BlockNumActivity.this);
            add_block_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            add_block_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_blocknum_dialog);

            final EditText editTextNameAddBlockNum = (EditText) add_block_dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextNameAddBlockNum);
            EditText editTextContactAddBlockNum = (EditText) add_block_dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextContactAddBlockNum);
            final EditText editTextNumberAddBlockNum = (EditText) add_block_dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberAddBlockNum);
            Button buttonAddAddBlockNum = (Button) add_block_dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddAddBlockNum);

            buttonAddAddBlockNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (editTextNameAddBlockNum.getText().toString().equals(null)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"plz insert a name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (editTextNumberAddBlockNum.getText().toString().equals(null)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"plz insert a number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (!editTextNumberAddBlockNum.getText().toString().equals(null) && !editTextNumberAddBlockNum.getText().toString().equals(null) ) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"successfuly saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            add_block_dialog.show();
```

but when i click on the button it always shows `successfuly saved`. even when the edit texts are null.

Comment: Better to do `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextNameAddBlockNum.getText().toString()))`

Comment: `editTextNumberAddBlockNum.getText().toString().equals(null)` is totally wrong. Instead use `if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextNumberAddBlockNum.getText().toString()))` or `if(editTextNumberAddBlockNum.getText().toString().length<=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
if (editTextNameAddBlockNum.getText().toString().equals(null))
```

To

```
if (editTextNameAddBlockNum.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
buttonAddAddBlockNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editTextNameAddBlockNum.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"plz insert a name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (editTextNumberAddBlockNum.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"plz insert a number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (!editTextNumberAddBlockNum.getText().toString().equals("") && !editTextNumberAddBlockNum.getText().toString().equals("") ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"successfuly saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```